# C# How do you implement an Equal() method in a for loop array?

Tags: c#, arrays, inheritance, methods, equals

I have an Equal() method to see if the OrderNumber was already put in or not. I'm not sure how to call it during the for loop array.

This is my Equal Method

```
public override bool Equals(object e)
    {
        bool equal;
        Order temp = (Order)e;
        if(OrderNumber == temp.OrderNumber)
            equal = true;
        else
            equal = false;
        return equal;
    }
```

And this is the input portion of the main()

```
public class week_6
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ShippedOrder[] InputOrder = new ShippedOrder[5];
    int x;
    for(x= 0; x < InputOrder.Length; ++x)
    {
    InputOrder[x] = new ShippedOrder();


    Console.Write("Enter order number:  ");
    InputOrder[x].OrderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Enter customer name:  ");
    InputOrder[x].CustName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter quantity:  ");
    InputOrder[x].Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

The SippedOrder class is a child class of the Order class. The program compiles and runs fine without trying to do anything with the equals method.

I'm trying to have it where if they put the same order number it says "Sorry, the order number '###' is a duplicate.
Please reenter"

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: can you please be clearer with your question? Which part are you asking? How to take an `Equals()` method override and use it to determine whether to present user with an console message? Or are you asking how to break the loop when you detect that the same order was entered using your `Equals()` override?

Comment: I'm just trying to compare entered ordernumber with previous ones enterred. And if they are the same the message pops up. I'm not sure how to do this, thought the equals method would be the best way to do it.

Comment: Make sure you also override `GetHashCode` if you override `Equals`.  This will be especially important if you choose to use a `HashSet` to keep track of previous orders.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a [`HashSet<ShippedOrder>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead of array. And use it's `Add()` method. If `Add()` returns false, you can display your message "Sorry, the order number '###' is a duplicate. Please reenter"

**EDIT:**

```
HashSet<ShippedOrder> InputOrder = new HashSet<ShippedOrder>();
```

and you can add items to it like this.

```
ShippedOrder order  = new ShippedOrder();
order.OrderNumber = 1;
order.CustName = "Foo";
order.Quantity = 10;

bool result = InputOrder.Add(order);

if (!result)
{
   // add failed; display message
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm pretty new to c# and the equal/gethash methods. How would I implement HashSet<ShippedOrder> into my code?

Comment: @Joel see my edit. Also, there is an example in the MSDN page and you can alway search for more examples for HashSet.

Answer (score 1):

This linq query might work.

```
var isDupe = InputOrder.Where(o => o.Equals(InputOrder[x])).Count() > 1;
```

Comment: If you just need one match, .Any() is preferable to using Count(), as Any will stop at the first match and is also clearer :)

Comment: Yeah, but I am looking for two or more matches.

Comment: Thanks for the help, how would I add this to the forloop?

Comment: Put it anywhere in the for loop and follow it up with an if statement. If isDupe is true, print your warning message and break out of the loop.